# Android effectively cursor usage?

Tags: android, cursor, android-sqlite

In my Android activity, I use rawquery many times. And I use a static cursor for that rawquery. My question is: should i close my cursor before execute another rawquery or just leave it open til all the rawqueries are executed (close only once).

I try both and the result is the same. But in term of performance/debug, which one is better?

Comment: "But in term of performance, which one is better?" You can easily answer this question yourself if you use tools like [DDMS](https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html).

Answer (score 0):

you **should** close your cursor after finishing with it. otherwise you will consume all the allowed cursor resources for your application (it is limited) and will get an exception.

making static does not make it one open cursor for all. remember that it is static on the java side; there is a native side here that uses new resources for each opened cursor. you need to free these resources.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't close the cursor after each use, you are leaking memory quite badly. What you are actually doing is creating a new cursor with every query, but using a single static reference to refer to only the newest. (References to the older cursors are lost.)

Unclosed cursors can also cause fatal errors further down the line, if (for example) the runtime tries to do some garbage collection. The SQLiteDatabase's `finalize()` method (called on garbage collection) will throw an exception if it notices that some cursors are still open, and this can kill your app.